# Running go-bindata in a VM causes an input/output error?

Tags: go, virtual-machine

I am running go-bindata in my VM. It seems to prompt an input/output error, without any further description.
However when i run the same go-bindata on my host OS, there is absolutely no error. What am i missing here?

Steps:

```
1) Use an oracle virtualbox VM . Enable networking and start the vm. Download the go-bindata and check if it is installed . You can do so by checking the help menu(go-bindata -h) or the version(go-bindata -version). I get a proper help menu and version 3.1.0 when i do that.

2) Now power off the vm, disable the networking and start the vm again.
3) run go-bindata now( or again you can just do go-bindata -h or go-bindata -version). I am getting an error here. 

-bash: /path/to/bin/go-bindata: Input/output error
```

There is no more description after that.
I checked the /var/log/dmesg but i see no bad blocks issue there as well.

Comment: We can't tell what's going on from that. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Marc Added some description now. I guess this should be reproducible now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. Issue is when you have bad blocks on disk, you tend to get this input/output error. But this error can come for so many reasons. So it's hard to tell what's the exact cause of it, but in my case i tried doing a lot of trial and error stuff to get a hold of it and turns out the VM needed to be restarted by sending a shutdown signal and not powering off the machine. You get those options easily while closing an Oracle VirtualBox machine. Thanks :)